# New div's will not appear under fixed header

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a fixed header image as my first div, but then I obviously want to have more divs/sections underneath it to complete the webpage.

However when I try and do this, I can still only see the header image and not the div position underneath it.

Anyone know why? Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5atv9c3/

I tried using things like:

```
top: 0px; //for the fixed element
margin-top: 100%; //for the sub-divs in the container
position: relative/absolute; //for the sub-divs in the container
```

But none of them worked :/ So yeah all help is appreciated

Comment: Why .header has to be fixed?

Comment: So you want the top edge of the `.packages` to be right below the bottom edge of `.header`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined your `.header` block, it will have a height of 100% of the screen height.

If you want `.packages` to appear right below `.header`, set the top margin of `.packages` to be 100%.

Since the `.header` is fixed, you need to set the top offset and the z-index as follows:

```
.header {
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/u8bt9wda/

Answer (score 0):

You can do following things.

give fixed height to header

```
.header {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/GZJVpxU.jpg") 
    height: 400px; //fixed height
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Add padding of header's height into packages

```
.packages{
   padding-top:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you give header `position:fixed;` So, next div position start from `top:0;` So, they hide back to first fixed div.

To make div visible give top position to second div and position:relative

```
.packages {
    padding: 40px 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 500px;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s5atv9c3/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/s5atv9c3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5atv9c3/3/)